# Python pandas asof join on groups

Tags: python, join, pandas

I have two pandas data frame X and Y, and each contains intraday price and time data for the past month. I would like to run asof join of Y on X, i.e. we take the prevailing price of Y each time we see an update on X. I would like to run an intraday analysis (because of the overnight effects)

The code I have right now is

```
Y_asof = Y.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: x.asof(X.index))
```

However, this returns an error saying that

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'asof'
```

It was working when i run

```
Y_asof = Y.apply(lambda x: x.asof(X.index))
```

Sample data of X:

```
                                 Mid        Date
Time                                            
2015-09-15 13:02:03.000049  7.575392  2015-09-15
2015-09-15 13:02:06.000049  7.575521  2015-09-15
2015-09-15 13:02:08.000049  7.575392  2015-09-15
2015-09-15 13:02:14.000049  7.575521  2015-09-15
2015-09-15 13:02:15.000048  7.575649  2015-09-15
```

Sample data of Y:

```
                                 Mid        Date
Time                                            
2015-09-15 12:00:00.443000  4.650894  2015-09-15
2015-09-15 12:00:00.443000  4.650899  2015-09-15
2015-09-15 12:00:06.321000  4.650894  2015-09-15
2015-09-15 12:00:06.322000  4.650884  2015-09-15
2015-09-15 12:00:10.839000  4.650894  2015-09-15
```

Could anyone please help? Thanks much!

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data?

Comment: Hi Alexander, I am attaching the head of each data sets. Note, the complete data set is month long data.

Answer (score 2):

[asof](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.asof.html) is a Series method, rather than a DataFrame one. It works on the Time column:

```
In [11]: Y.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: x["Time"].asof(X.index))
Out[11]:
Time                                 0                           1                           2                           3                           4
Date
2015-09-15  2015-09-15 12:00:00.443000  2015-09-15 12:00:00.443000  2015-09-15 12:00:06.321000  2015-09-15 12:00:06.322000  2015-09-15 12:00:10.839000
```

*When you do the apply, it's across each row (which is a Series).*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help Andy. This works. But how would I get the as of join on the entire data frame. I would like to see the Mid price column as well. Also, why would Y_asof = Y.apply(lambda x: x.asof(X.index)) work if asof is method on pd.Series only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe pandas throws an error because `Y.groupby('Date')` creates a `GroupBy` object which does not have the method `asof`. If you're just using `groupby` as a way to sort by date, you could do `Y_asof = Y.sort('Date').apply(lambda x: x.asof(X.index))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[pandas 0.19 has an asof join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0190-enhancements-asof-merge). Since you want the most recent `Y` for each `X`:

```
pd.merge(X, Y, on='time')
```